# adding datasources in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jndi

I want to configure a datasource through the datasource subsystem in a jboss-as-7.1.1.Final server installed on a Mac V 10.13.1
I already provided a JDBC driver

So I added this piece of code in the file `standalone.xml`

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">

    <datasources>
   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS">
      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EJB3</connection-url>
         <driver>com.mysql</driver>
      <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
      <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
      </pool>
      <security>
        <user-name>test</user-name>
        <password>test</password>
      </security>
      <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
        <share-prepared-statements/>
      </statement>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
      <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
      </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>

    <extensions>
       ...
</server>
```

But when I run the serverI got this error:

```
14:28:35,894 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:266) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[5,5]
Message: JBAS014789: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:1.2}datasources' encountered
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.unexpectedElement(ParseUtils.java:85) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:351) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

standalone.xml already has a section for datasources.

You shoud look for `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">` section and add it there